# Add DATA from JTable to another one

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that displays a list of questions.
What I want to do is when I click on a question among the list view it will be added in the other JTable ( and the question still in the first JTable).
I must of course add a click event on the JTable but after I know what to do.

[The result of the execution of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqkTM.png)

```
    List<Question> questions=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Question> questions2=new ArrayList<>(); 
    table_1 = new JTable();
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(table_1);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    setLayout(groupLayout);
    initDataBindings();

}
protected void initDataBindings() {
    JTableBinding<Question, List<Question>, JTable> jTableBinding = SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, questions, table);
    //
    BeanProperty<Question, String> questionBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("contenu");
    jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(questionBeanProperty).setColumnName("Contenu");
    //
    BeanProperty<Question, Collection<Reponse>> questionBeanProperty_1 = BeanProperty.create("reponses");
    jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(questionBeanProperty_1).setColumnName("Les reponses");
    //
    BeanProperty<Question, String> questionBeanProperty_2 = BeanProperty.create("niveauDeDifficulte");
    jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(questionBeanProperty_2).setColumnName("Niveau de difficult\u00E9");
    //
    jTableBinding.bind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

```
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            questions2.add(questions.get(table.getSelectedRow()));

        }
    });
```

Comment: you have to test if is there selection to avoids `ArrayIndex....Exception`, e.g. `if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1)`